# How to avoid duplicate System.Random inside foreach loops?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use System.Random inside a foreach loop but because it uses time to generate I'm encountering an issue where loops completed at the same time yield the same result.

How could this be solved? (Needs to be random each loop)

Example:

```
  foreach (var entry in somelist)
  {
    System.Random rand = new System.Random();
    int random_number = rand.Next(2, 13);
    echo($"{random_number}");
  }
```

The result of the above code will be similar to this: 44444666662222288888

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should keep a single instance of Random, instead of reinitializing it everytime

```
System.Random rand = new System.Random();

foreach (var entry in somelist)
{
    int random_number = rand.Next(2, 13);
    echo($"{random_number}");
}
```

Random is initialized using identical seed values based on System Clock and therefore, if you were to reinitialize it in quick succession (as in the loop in the sample code given in OP), there is every chance you might end up with duplicates.

For example,

```
Random rand1 = new Random();
Random rand2 = new Random();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
Random rand3 = new Random();

Console.WriteLine(rand1.Next());
Console.WriteLine(rand2.Next());
Console.WriteLine(rand3.Next());
```

In the above code, it is most likely that `rand1` and `rand2` produces identical numbers. However, `rand3` could be different as it is initialized after 2 seconds.

In fact, rand1 and rand2 is most likely to produce same series if you were to generate n random numbers.

```
  var r1 = Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(x=>rand1.Next());
  var r2 = Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(x=>rand2.Next());
```

Comment: Random is initialized based on System Clock and therefore, if you were to reinitialize it in quick succession, there is every chance you might end up with duplicates. I have updated the answer with the same explanation

Comment: @panoskarajohn The difference is the seed you pass in to `Random`. When inside a loop you pass several iterations the same seed so the value is the same. That's why it's good practice to keep one instance of `Random`

Comment: It is initialized outside of the loop which saves time and resources on the CPU and Memory that would other wise be wasted declaring, constructing, initializing, and then disposing of the random number generator with each loop. It just speeds up the loop. Short runs wouldn't be noticeable but long runs iterating over thousands of entries in the list would save a noticeable amount of time. It is also seeded with the system time so quick loops in succession would seed it with the same timestamp before it can change.

Comment: Thanks, I presumed that initiating it outside of the loop would give the same result each time. Works perfectly now :D