# Find random object where integer is less than value

Tags: c#, linq

I want to find a random enemy that has `power <= maxUnitPower`, and it has to also be `power <= remainingPower`.

I wrote some logic to manage tha scenario that creates a new List with all enemies that has less than `power`, then I pick a random enemy in that List, and check if it's `power` is less than the `remainingPower`:

```
WorldObjectData GetRandomEnemy(EnemyWaveData wave, int remainingPower)
{
    List<WorldObjectData> relevantEnemies = new List<WorldObjectData>();

    for (int i = 0; i < enemyList.enemies.Count; i++)
    {
        if(enemyList.enemies[i].power <= wave.maxUnitPower)
        {
            relevantEnemies.Add(enemyList.enemies[i]);
        }
    }

    return GetEnemyWithinRemainingPower(relevantEnemies, remainingPower);
}

WorldObjectData GetEnemyWithinRemainingPower(List<WorldObjectData> enemies, int remainingPower)
{
    WorldObjectData enemy = enemies[Random.Range(0, enemies.Count)];

    if (enemy.power <= remainingPower)
        return enemy;
    else
        return GetEnemyWithinRemainingPower(enemies, remainingPower);
}
```

I want to do this in Linq instead since this seems very messy, but have no idea how to achieve it. How can it be done?

Comment: Try something like this : List<WorldObjectData> relevantEnemies = enemyList.enemies.Where(x => (x.power <= wave.maxUnitPower) && (x.power <= remainingPower)).ToList();

Comment: Just as a suggestion for the future, when you call a method recursivly like in the else case of 'GetEnemyWithinRemainingPower', use at least a subset of the enemies list by removing the enemy that you already know doesn't fulfill the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Enumerable.Where` to first Filter the enemies that matches the condition and then use `OrderBy( s => random.NextDouble() ).First()` to get the random one. For example,

```
var random = new Random();
var enemy = enemyList.Where(x=>x.power <= maxUnitPower && x.power <=remainingPopwer)
                     .OrderBy( s => random.NextDouble() )
                     .First();
```

Do note that it would better if you could keep a class level instance of random than recreating it each time you want to generate the Random Enemy.

Random is initialized using identical seed values based on System Clock and therefore, if you were to reinitialize it in quick succession, there is every chance you might end up with duplicates. Please follow the explanation in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471110/how-to-avoid-duplicate-system-random-inside-foreach-loops/59471148#59471148) to understand issue poised by quick reinitialization of Random

Answer (score 0):

[You should check where method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8)

I suggest trying something like this :

```
List<int> relevantEnemies = enemyList.enemies.power.Where(x => x >= wave.maxUnitPower).ToList();
```

Not sure if it will work exactly this example, but you can tweak it to suit your problem